# How can I access a view of an activity from another activity

Tags: android

I need to hide the tabs of a TabHost from a child activity. I tried `getParent()` and it didnt work

Also tried :

```
TabHost th = (TabHost) ((TabsActivity)getBaseContext()).findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        th.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

But it throws a nullpointer

Answer (score 1):

Never directly access `Views` owned by other `Activities` from the current `Activity`, because they might have been recycled in the meantime (because the other `Activity` might have got destroyed in the meantime).

You need to communicate with the other `Activity` in a standard way. For example, your child `Activity` can return a result to the parent `Activity`, which it can then interpret (you can put the value to the `Intent`). Another solution is using a static variable, but this is not too nice and has risks if you're not careful enough.

For more information about communication between Activities, see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to directly manipulate the view hierarchy of an Activity not currently in the foreground because it likely would have been paused and stopped, in which case its UI has already been destroyed and won't be rebuilt until it comes back into the foreground.  You should consider what things take place in the Activity lifecycle to help you solve this.  A quick and dirty solution could be that your Activity hosting the tabs has a public static variable that can be set by other Activities; such that when it resumes running in the foreground it can check that variable and make Views visible or not as needed